# ggplot2: Plot two different Densities in the same Plot of the same Variable before and after a Cutoff

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

My goal is to plot two different densities in the same plot of the same variable. I want to do this as it is common to show robustness of the forcing variable (here z) in a Regression Discontinuity Design. In the code below, I got it working however I do not want the density to be plotted before the cutoff (here 0) if it the key is "above"  and vice-versa. Also, the graph should not just be hidden because of the smoothing. It should start computing the density just until (or start) the cutoff.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0)
y <- rnorm(500, mean = 2)
z <- append(x,y)

d <- tibble(value = z, key = ifelse(z <= 0, "below", "above"))

ggplot(d) +
  geom_density(aes(z, group = key)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0))
```

Does anybody know how to implement this? For linear regressions I got it working, but with geom_density() it plots the other side of the cutoff as well and smoothes it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trim = TRUE` in `geom_density` to only calculate density over the range of values in the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0)
y <- rnorm(500, mean = 2)
z <- append(x,y)

d <- tibble(value = z, key = ifelse(z <= 0, "below", "above"))

ggplot(d) +
    # added fill for easier discrimination
    geom_density(aes(value, group = key, fill = key), 
                 alpha = 0.5, trim = TRUE) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), lty = 2, colour = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what i have been looking for! thanks